# python asyncio as_completed doubts

Tags: python, python-asyncio, sigint

After quite some reading on asyncio (I'm totally noob about it), I've managed to write simple programs that do what I want them to do.

Yet, I have some dobuts regarding as_completed method: how it works internally and how it impacts my cpu usage.

So, let there be the following snippet:

```
#as_completed_example.py
import asyncio
import tqdm
import datetime
import sys
import signal
import random
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async def heavy_load(i):
    #tqdm.tqdm.write('#DEBUG    '+datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+' '+str(i))
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
    return None
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async def main():
    length  =   int(sys.argv[1])
    inputs  =   list(range(length))
    pbar    =   tqdm.tqdm(total=len(inputs),position=0,leave=True,bar_format='#PROGRESS {desc}: {percentage:.3f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}')
    tasks   =   [heavy_load(i) for i in inputs]
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        _ = await future
        pbar.update(1)
        pbar.refresh()            
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
def sigint_handler(signum,frame):
    tqdm.tqdm.write('#INFO '+datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+' user aborted execution!')
    sys.exit(0)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
if(__name__=='__main__'):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,sigint_handler)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If I call it as python3 `as_completed_example.py 1000` , it works flawlessly. Yet, If I call it as `as_completed_example.py 1000000 (large number)`, I observe that my progressbar is stucked at 0% for quite some time:

-While my progressbar is at 0%,

--**what is happening in my cpu?** Because It takes one core to the 100% usage

--**why am I not getting any `future` from as_completed after quite some time**?

Comment: irrelevant, indeed. Let's just guess it's a heavy_load

Comment: I edited the snippet to ```await asyncio.sleep(random.random())```. Behaviour remains the same, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions here, which should be avoided on SO if possible. But there is a simple answer to your first two questions. Why does it pin a single CPU, and why is there a delay before the progress bar prints? There's just a lot of *single-threaded* work to do.

`asyncio` runs everything in a single thread, unless you explicitly do otherwise. The tasks you're building require quite a bit of setup internally in `asyncio`, especially the call to `as_completed`. You can look [at the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b626d2218c03127502025ccdf93d555e0487ea95/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L557) for that for details, but it must:

- Make a `set` out of your futures. Not too expensive, but not free.
- Set up producer and consumer queues to control tasks not yet run and tasks that have completed. For such large numbers of tasks as you're using, this is likely to cause multiple, large allocations, which can be a real killer.
- Schedule callbacks to be run as the futures complete. This mostly moves them from queue to the other, and removes them from the `set` of futures, none of which is free.
- Yield each future

The fact that there is a lot of setup here, and that this takes an appreciable amount of time, can be easily seen by varying the sizes of your inputs. On my laptop, the time before any futures are run really falls off a cliff starting at size `100000`. Furthermore, it drops non-linearly, which suggests that this size is particularly bad for the memory hierarchy on my machine (e.g., many more cache misses after this size).

I also find it likely that the `asyncio` event loop's *resolution* is playing a role here. Time has to tick along for the futures to be consumed. You're creating many futures, many of which are completed at nearly the same time (as @user4815162342 rightly pointed out in the comments), within a single tick of the event loop. That's a lot of work per tick of the event loop, and it must all be done on a single thread.

This is pretty clear, looking at the fact that the whole thing takes longer than 1 second to complete. The maximum sleep interval is 1 second, because `random.random` gives you values on `[0, 1.0)`, but whole application takes much longer. So there's more than "one second's worth" of work going on here, and again, all in a single thread.

Comment: I'll edit the post to remove the SIGINT question and GLADLY I'll accept your answer. Thank you SOO much!